# C# Update Table Button Not Working Automatically

Tags: c#, button, sql-update

I have some c# code and recently I added a button to the form designer which runs a simple update table query (update a SQL table). The table is updated as I would expect when I manually click the button in Debug mode, however when I run the entire program, it appears the method/button to update the SQL table is either ignored or simply not being picked up. As I mentioned, this works fine when I go into Debug and click on the button manually, however what I need it to do is run the method and click the button automatically as it is doing for the other methods. I have gone through this hundreds of times and am at the end of the road. Below is my code;

```
 private void updateClosedModuleState()
        {
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection saConn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();

            saConn.ConnectionString = GlobalDef.strSQLConnection;
            //MessageBox.Show(saConn.ConnectionString);
            try
            {
                saConn.Open();
                SqlCommand command = saConn.CreateCommand();
                command.CommandTimeout = saConn.ConnectionTimeout;
                command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                command.CommandText = " UPDATE SATA_AllocationObject "
                                      + " SET State = REPLACE(State, 'A', 'I') "
                                      + " where AllocationObjectType = 4 "
                                      + " and Hostkey in (select hostkey from TRAN_UnitEClosedModules)";
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception act)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ooops! Error " + act.Message.ToString() + " when updating Module State");
            }
            finally
            {
                saConn.Close();
            }

            pictureBox19.Visible = true;
        }
```

This is the code for the button click;

```
 private void cmdUpdateClosedModuleState_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {

                updateClosedModuleState();
            }
```

Lastly, these are the method details in the form designer;

```
this.cmdUpdateClosedModuleState.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(517, 114);
            this.cmdUpdateClosedModuleState.Name = "cmdUpdateClosedModuleState";
            this.cmdUpdateClosedModuleState.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(107, 23);
            this.cmdUpdateClosedModuleState.TabIndex = 41;
            this.cmdUpdateClosedModuleState.Text = "UpdateModState";
            this.cmdUpdateClosedModuleState.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.cmdUpdateClosedModuleState.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.cmdUpdateClosedModuleState_Click);
```

I have also tried to use a TableAdapter and use a Fill to update the SQL Table via the button, and that works...only when I click the button in Debug mode;

```
private void newupdate()
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
          
            this.sATA_AllocationObject1TableAdapter.Fill(this.moduleSignupTestDataSet.SATA_AllocationObject1);
        }
```

I assigned a buttton to run the Fill on the TableAdapter;

```
private void newupdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //this.sATA_AllocationObject1TableAdapter.Fill(this.moduleSignupTestDataSet.SATA_AllocationObject1);
            newupdate();
        }
```

So in a nutshell, I need the program to run this method like it does with all the other ones without my intervention.

I have attached a photo of the form - when I click 'Run All' everything runs except for the UpdateClosedModState; [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJryA.png

The code behind the Run All command is;

```
private void cmdRunAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            begin();
        }
```

In the form designer we have;

```
this.cmdRunAll.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(381, 375);
            this.cmdRunAll.Name = "cmdRunAll";
            this.cmdRunAll.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(107, 21);
            this.cmdRunAll.TabIndex = 10;
            this.cmdRunAll.Text = "Run All";
            this.cmdRunAll.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.cmdRunAll.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.cmdRunAll_Click);
```

And at the start of the form, we have this to begin running the app;

```
if (args.Length > 0)
            {
                lArgsExists = true;
                //                strDetails = strDetails + ": About to run app.";
                //                runApp(args[0], lArgsExists);
                begin();
            }
        }
        public void runApp(string cnfgPath, bool gui)
        {
            if (gui == true)
            {
                strDetails = strDetails + " Running app.";
                begin();
            }
            else
            {
                textBox2.Text = GlobalDef.appStatus.ToString();
                begin();
                //MessageBox.Show("Opening form!");
            }
        }
        public void begin()
        {

            String sqlServerLogin = GlobalDef.sqlServerlogin;
            String password = GlobalDef.password;
            String instanceName = GlobalDef.instanceName;
            String remoteSvrName = GlobalDef.remoteSvrName;
            string strNow = DateTime.Now.Day + "/" + DateTime.Now.Month + "/" + DateTime.Now.Year;
            string strSQLConnection = GlobalDef.strSQLConnection;
            textBox2.Text = GlobalDef.appStatus.ToString();
            //string path = @"E:\Allocator\StudentAllocatorTest\logs\Error.log";
            string path = GlobalDef.path;
            // This text is added only once to the file.
            if (!File.Exists(path))
            {
                // Create a file to write to.
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine("Error details");
                }
            }
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))
            {
                sw.WriteLine();
                sw.WriteLine("******************************************");
                sw.WriteLine();
                sw.WriteLine(strDetails.ToString());
                sw.WriteLine("******************************************");
                sw.WriteLine();
                sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + ": Starting load for " + GlobalDef.instanceName);
            }

            try
            {
                string connString = GlobalDef.connString;
                OracleConnection oraCon = new OracleConnection(connString);

                System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
                conn.ConnectionString =
                 "data source=" + remoteSvrName + ";" +
                 "persist security info=true;initial catalog=" + instanceName + ";User Id=" + sqlServerLogin + "; Password=" + password + ";";


                // Clear transfer tables before running any subroutine

                clearTransTables();

                // Loads Department details into SA TransTables
                updateDepartment(oraCon, strSQLConnection);

                // Loads new POSA modules into SA TransTables
                updatePOSA(oraCon, strSQLConnection, path);

                // Loads new POSY modules into SA TransTables
                updatePOSY(oraCon, strSQLConnection, path);

                // Remove open option links for modules which do not have the timetable flag checked
                RemoveUnneededOOCourses(oraCon, strSQLConnection, path);

                // Loads top-level OO structure into SA TransTables 
                OpenOption(oraCon, strSQLConnection, path);

                // Loads Dept level OO structure into SA TransTables
                OptionByDept(oraCon, strSQLConnection, path);

                // Links OOByDept Allocation Objects to OO Objects via TransTables
                linkOOAndOOByDept(path);

                // Loads new Course modules into SA TransTables
                updateCourse(oraCon, strSQLConnection, path);

                // Links OO courses to OOByDept AllocationObjects via TransTables
                OpenOptionCourses(oraCon, strSQLConnection, path);

                //Adds All Courses to various hidden groups via TransTables
                updateAllHidden(oraCon, strSQLConnection, path);

                // Loads new students into SA TransTables

                //TransferStudent(oraCon, strSQLConnection);

                // Loads prerequisite allocations into SA TransTables
                UploadPrerequisites(oraCon, strSQLConnection);

                //button1_Click();

                // Loads Closed Modules from UnitE to TRAN_UnitEClosedModules
                
                uploadUnitEClosedModules(oraCon, strSQLConnection);

                //Runs the transfer service which loads the data in the TransTables into the database
                runTransferservice(path);

                ///
                newupdate();

                // update Closed Modules to 'I' State

                updateClosedModuleState();

                // Used to create a structure for programmes which had yet to be set up by faculties
                //   DefaultCourseStructure(oraCon, strSQLConnection);

                // Creates UNITe course enrolments and cancels changed course selections
                uploadAllocationsToUNITe(oraCon, strSQLConnection, path);
                //  pictureBox11.Visible = true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + ": Completed load for " + GlobalDef.instanceName);
                }
                Application.Exit();
            }
        }

        

        private void updateDepartment(OracleConnection oraCon, string strSQLConnection)
        {
            try
            {
```

....and it goes on with the subroutines listed above.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: And where is the code behind the Run All command? If something is not called from that command then you should look there not in the single button event handler

Comment: command.ExecuteNonQuery(); returns and integer indicating the number of rows that changed.  Verify if you are getting zero.  Is AllocationObjectType and primary key in the database?  If it is a primary key then you have to use Insert if key is not in database.  Usually I recommend doing a Select to verify that key is in database to help isolate what is really wrong.

Comment: @Steve thank you for the quick reply. The code behind the Run All command is;
```
private void cmdRunAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            begin();
        }
```
And in the form designer, we have;
```
cmdRunAll_Click
```
And this is in the main form;
```

            if (args.Length > 0)
            {
                lArgsExists = true;
                //                strDetails = strDetails + ": About to run app.";
                //                runApp(args[0], lArgsExists);
                begin();
```

Comment: @jdweng thank you for replying - AllocationObjectType is not a primary key. I presume you meant verify ExecuteNonQuery(); via Debug? I placed a breakpoint and went into Debug mode and the query is being run fine. I then check the Database and the table has been updated. This works fine in Debug if the button is manually clicked to call the method however it doesn't run automatically when I the whole program runs. All the other methods are picked up and they work fine.

Comment: @GBM please add the code to your question using the [edit] link. As you can see, code in comments is pretty unreadable.

Comment: @Steve a thousand apologies - I have now edited the main question at the bottom.

Comment: I'm completely confused about this code: are you using Oracle or SQL Server? WHy do you create an `OracleConnection` then not use it and instead use `SqlConnection`?

Comment: When you do a select query the database is read and a link is created between the rows of the database and the datatable which is filled by the data adapter.  You are then changing the values in the datatable.  You then should use the datatable property AcceptChanges to put the data back into the database.  So two thing must happen 1) The SQLCommand must be the same for the SELECT and the ACCEPT CHANGES so the linking is maintained. 2) Use Command builder : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0

Comment: A DataTable Command has four types 1) Select 2) Delete 3) Update 4) Insert.  For the Accept Changes to work you need to have all four types.  The Commandbuilder takes a Select query and automatically creates the other three types.

Comment: @Charlieface the OracleConnection was not meant to be there - I forgot to remove that when I copied and pasted the code to my question. I have now amended.

Comment: Here's an update - I think I might have figured it out. I placed a breakpoint on ExecuteNonQuery(); and right clicked on the breatpoint and selected the When Hit option, and checked the 'continue execution' box. I then ran the program and it worked. I also ran it from Task Scheduler and it worked. It seems the breakpoint did the trick, or is it patching a problem and not fixing it?